# Derivation of F from ¬E V F and ¬E -> F

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, derivation-of-formulae

I want to derive F from ¬E V F and ¬E -> F

Here is what I have done:

1. ¬E -> F //    hyp
2. ¬E V F  //   hyp
3. ¬E   //    AA
4. F   //   E ->(2)
5. F   //   AA
6. ```
   ¬F  //   AA
   ```
7. F   //    E ¬(6)
8. F      //    Ev(2-4,5-7)

I don't know if I can assume ¬F like in 6 and deduce that I have F because there is a contradiction, Is it a good writing ?

Comment: But you don't need line (6) to prove $F\to F$; line (5) alone would be enough.

Comment: Ok thank you, and what can i put for justification ?

Comment: If on line (5) you start a conditional subproof with assumption $F$, then repeat $F$, then end the subproof, this would mean $F\to F$.

Comment: You can end the proof on line 5 citing disjunction elimination "VE" (see below)

Comment: I assumed to apply [disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination), you were trying to prove $\neg E \to F, F\to F, \neg E \vee F$.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand, for you it is not possible to do like I did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end the proof on line $5$ citing disjunction-elimination "$\vee$E"

For instance...

$ \neg E \vee F, \neg E \to F \vdash F $

$\{1\} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:1. \neg E \vee F \:\:\:\:\:\:\:$    premise

$\{2\} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: 2. \neg E \to F \:\:\:\:\:\:$    premise

$\{3\} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: 3. \neg E \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$    Assumption

$\{2,3\} \:\:\:\: 4. F \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$    $2,3$ Modus Ponens

$\{5\} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: 5. F \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$    Assumption

$\{1,2\} \:\:\:\: 6. F \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$    $1, 3, 4, 5, 5$ Disjunction-Elimination

Notice on line $5$ you are able to conclude the very thing you assume, completing the second derivation needed for $\vee$E

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Done ! Some minutes to find it but it's ok hahahahaha